# Find the representation of series of $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Develop in the series of powers around the corresponding origin (Taylor or Laurent) the following functions, indicating the region of uniform convergence

$$\frac{z-1}{z+1}$$

**My attempt:**
Let $f(z)=\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ note $f$ isn't analytic in $z=-1$.

Moreover,

$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z+1)(z-1)^{-1}}$

Let $g(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}$ Note, $g$ is analytic in $z=-1$.

Here i'm stuck, can someone help me?

Comment: Have you noticed that $\frac{z-1}{z+1} = 1 - \frac{2}{z+1}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{z-1}{z+1} = \frac {z+1-2}{z+1} = 1-\frac {2}{1+z} = $$

$$ 1-2\sum_0^\infty (-1)^nz^n$$

The series converges on $|z|<1$